# Xamarin.Forms ListView set SelectedItem by Code

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

How can I set the `SelectedItem` of a ListView in my Code? My problem is, that is isn't highlighted when I preselect an item in my code. The ListView is defined in the xaml file.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

My ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel
{
    List<MyItem> Items {get; set;}
    MyItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel() 
    {
        Items = new List<MyItem>{ ... };
        SelectedItem = Items.First();
    }
}
```

But when I show the view, it is not highlighting the selected item. When I click on an item, it is highlighted and set correctly. I've played around with property changed, but this shouldn't have an effect, because the property is set right in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your view to update when properties on `MyViewModel` change, that class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Here's an example:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

But **importantly** you must call `OnPropertyChanged` in your setters, so your `SelectedItem` property will need to look something like this:

```
MyItem _selectedItem;
MyItem SelectedItem {
  get {
    return _selectedItem;
  }
  set {
    _selectedItem = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
  } 
}
```

Lots of good information on MVVM in Xamarin Forms here: [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)

Comment: As I wrote: I've tried this ("played around with property changed"). The problem was the highlighting.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I see that now. My apologies, I missed the last paragraph of your question. You will probably want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but that doesn't solve your current issue. What happens if you set SelectedItem="{ Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay }"?

Comment: I will try it. The binding is working at least from the view to the model, so it is a bit strange. I've never seen `OneWayToSource` as default binding mode. I may provide a sample project, if I have time.

Comment: Agreed, that would be a strange default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495409/setting-the-initial-selected-item-when-binding-to-a-listviews-selecteditem-prop?rq=1#comment52863782_32501340 might be helpful.

Comment: Ye I've seen this behavior. I'am just ignoring `null` values (e.g. from the initialization of the binding) in the bound property, because in my list there is always one selected item.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was simply this.... (for example select automatically the first element with one element)

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    if (MyList.Count == 1)
                {
                    List_CheckPoint.SelectedItem = MyList[0];
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify that the xyz binding is two way.

`SelectedItem="{Binding xyz, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Note your selection might deselect if the collection changes. After I move/reorder my collection I always set xyz back to the original selection.